# using Siliverlight to animate one listbox sliding out and another sliding in ala iPhone

Tags: silverlight

I want to slide listBox1 out and listBox2 in in much the same way as the iPhone Ui navigates in Mail from accounts to folders, to messages etc.

I get the idea of recording storyboards in Blend, and triggering the play. What I'm stumped on at the moment is moving listBox1 out along the X axis, obviously I can change it's location but that doesn't "hide" it.  Or to put it another way, how do I move it "off stage"

I should also add that the listbox is in the middle of the app, so just sliding off the edge of the application area doesn't fly as the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikhil Kothari has done some great work in this area.

His framework called Silverlight FX allows you to do animations as you describe.

Take a look [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Effects-Transitions.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation the solution was very simple.  To slide the element "off stage" a Clip area needs to be defined. For example:

```
   <Grid x:Name="slideContainer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,640,480"/>
        </Grid.Clip>
```

Then create an animation that moves the element outside of the clip area.

With all that said, Nikhil Kothari is doing creat work in this area, as TreeUK answered.